# dynamically String input, unknown length, and convert to the wanted type in c language

Tags: c, dynamic, input

I need to convert an inputted string to struct array.
The input pattern is:
City age_1 name_1, age_2 name_2,.....age_n name_n end_of_city.

My struct:

```
 typedef struct Node{
    int age;
    char name[30];
}Node;
```

can I dynamically allocate a struct array for all the data?
The length of string is unknown!

Comment: As it will be known at execution time, dynamic allocation seems the good choice indeed.

Comment: Provide some sample lines of data.  Better yet, post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

First get a city name. Then you get 2 input scanf("%s",&s)`. Now check whether`s`is end of city. If not then covert it to a`int` and get the name in a variable.

Now you maintain a list of nodes. Whenever you get `age` and `name` you create a node and add it to the list.

```
typedef struct Node{
    int age;
    char name[30];
    Node *next;
}Node;
```

For allocating node -

```
Node *head;
void insert(Node *head,int age,char* name)
{
    Node *temp=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->age=age;
    temp->next=NULL;
    strcpy(temp->name,name);
    Node *t=head;
    if(t==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
       while(t->next!=NULL)
         t=t->next;
       t->next=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is to get all the input as one string then to put it into a array struct. the city name saying that it's the start of the input, when the "end_of_city" says that it's the end of the data.
I'm looking for a way to get all the data by type.
Thank you.

Comment: @GTa.: I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GTa.: If the answer was useful please accept/upvote it..as that's what make this post useful to future users